# Girl looks into mirror, sees demon swimming towards her

Tags: identify-this-movie, horror, thriller

I remember watching parts of a movie on tv some years ago. I missed the beginning, and saw some parts from the middle and the end. I didn't really understand what was happening, but I can provide some details about what I remember (including the ending, so stop reading if you want to avoid spoilers):

- the movie had a very creepy atmosphere, and the image seemed to be quite desaturated if not black and white
- a guy was having some weird dreams (or visions?), including an ominous figure walking behind some pillars; the dreams always stopped before he could see who it was
- there were some messed up mirrors in a building, showing and/or doing horrible things (I think including killing people); apparently there was another world behind them, with a demon or several demons
- a demon was trying to come out into the real world, and several characters were trying to stop it
- the part I remember most clearly: in one scene, a girl went to a mirror and the demon was kinda swimming towards her from the other side; they joined hands, then the girl went into the mirror, somehow pushing the demon away; then I think the guy (who was in the room) smashed the mirror; I understood this as a self-sacrifice of the girl
- and the really creepy ending: the guy is having that weird dream again, and now he can see the figure - it's the girl from the previous scene

Some details may not be accurate, but that's how I remember them. I found "Into the Mirror" (2003) and "Mirrors" (2008) on wikipedia, but I can't find a description of the ending that matches what I remember. And I think I saw (those parts of) the movie before 2003.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sounds like **[Prince of Darkness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince_of_Darkness_%28film%29)** (1987) by John Carpenter.

Wikipedia's description matches the details you remember, including the creepy ending:

> At the end of the film, Marsh has the recurring dream again, except
>   now an apparently possessed Danforth is the figure emerging from the
>   building. Marsh appears to awaken, rolling over to find a gruesomely
>   disfigured Kelly lying in bed with him. Marsh awakens, screaming, and
>   then recovers enough to approach his bedroom mirror, hand
>   outstretched. The film cuts to black just before his fingers touch the
>   mirror.

Comment: +1 Matches the description in many points. One of *Carpenter*'s rather underestimated movies, but it really has some interresting features and a great atmosphere. Especially the dream message from the future was one of the most original ideas I've ever seen, haven't seen such a thing anywhere else.

Comment: Yep that was the movie. Funny that I didn't remember the disfigured Kelly and the 80's style. A good remake could be interesting. Btw the ending description in wikipedia is wrong, the one he sees in bed is also Catherine (identified by the hair)

Comment: Odd trivia notation - The leader of the street people is Alice Cooper. I also always wanted them to make the sequel that seemed to be implied.